# How to start executing some code after executing the asynchronous code in the body of the loop?

Tags: javascript

For example this code writes: "Here I am!" and then "0, 1, 2, 3..."

```
for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    //some async code
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(i);
  }, 2000);
}
console.log("Here I am!");
```

How can I get results from loop, and then execute next part of code? To obtain:
"0, 1, 2, 3 ... 10" and then "Here I am!"?

Comment: why did you need settimout inside for loop ?

Comment: After each request in async code there is one callback method which executes when you get response. Try reading [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/), or [that](http://callbackhell.com/). If you use jQuery, than your life would become much easier, take a look [here](http://callbackhell.com/), scroll down to check [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) method.

Comment: @Gagantous it's just example.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your asynchronous code in a promise and then use Promise.all() to wait for the result. Then print "Here am I" in a then

```js
function A(i){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(i);
            }, 2000);

    })
}
let promiseArray = [];
for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    //some async code
    promiseArray.push(A(i));
}

Promise.all(promiseArray).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Here I am!");
})
```